# Apache2 mod_evasive for only one virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, mod-security

I'm testing a scenario where, I'm hosting two-site on same machine with help of apache web server. I'm looking to enable mod_evasive for only one site. I don't see any way to get it working. Following is the scenario and things I have tried.

- Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache2 Web/httpd server
- enable host with respective conf files for wwww.site1.com and wwww.site2.com
- Install and enable mod_evasive with "apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive"
- I only want the mod_evasive for www.site1.com

Things I have tried.

[1] Enabling mod_evasive on global level and add following to site1.conf. This affects both site1 and site2.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
   DOSHashTableSize 3097
   DOSPageCount  2
   DOSSiteCount  10
   DOSPageInterval 10
   DOSSiteInterval 100
   DOSBlockingPeriod  10
   DOSLogDir   /var/log/mod_evasive
</IfModule>
```

[2] Disabling mod_evasive on globla level and load evasive module + conf on tthe site1. Still it applied for both the site.

[3] Added DOSBlockinfPeriod == 0 to site2. But still no luck.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive24.c>
    DOSBlockingPeriod 0
</IfModule>
```

Need help on configuration that allows mod_evasive for only one virtual host OR allow override props per virtual host ".conf" files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same version of mod_evasive installed on your system 2.4 or 2.0

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSBlockingPeriod 0
</IfModule>
```